# Convert SET ROWCOUNT n to TOP (n) when n could be 0

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, sql-limit

We are currently using SQL server 2016. Based on the Microsoft page [Deprecated Database Engine Features in SQL Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016), the `SET ROWCOUNT` is being deprecated. So we are trying to convert all `SET ROWCOUNT N` statements to `TOP(N)` statements. It seems very easy but we encountered a case where N is a parameter in a stored procedure, default to 0.

So in the old code, it is something like `SET ROWCOUNT @NumRows`. If `@NumRows` is 0, that means to turn off the `SET ROWCOUNT` option, so the following query will return all rows. But if we convert this to `TOP(@NumRows)`, that means it will return 0 row. To avoid this problem, we could add extra IF condition, if `@NumRows` is 0, set `@NumRows` to a huge number. Or we could add extra IF condition, if `@NumRows` is 0, then we use SELECT without TOP, else we do `SELECT TOP(N)` as usual.

But either of these solution will add extra code in the stored procedures, so my question is: is there an elegant way to convert `SET ROWCOUNT N` to `TOP (N)` considering that N could be 0?

Update: added stored procedure template

```
-- Default to 0, in this case, SET ROWCOUNT 0 will return all result
-- But if we change it to TOP(@rows), it returns no result.
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc1  
  @rows int = 0  
AS  
SET ROWCOUNT @rows
SELECT Col1 FROM table1
ORDER BY Col2
SET ROWCOUNT 0

-- In this case, the default is not 0
-- But the program that calls this stored procedure could pass in value 0. 
-- We also don't want to change default value for this stored procedure. 
-- So I think in this case, we may have to add IF @rows = 0, SET @rows = huge_number
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc2
  @rows int = 10
AS
SET ROWCOUNT @rows
SELECT Col3 FROM table2
ORDER BY Col4
SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

Comment: elegant? No. But you can say `select @NumRows = iif(@NumRows = 0, 2147483648, @NumRows)` before plugging it into your `top` clause. That said, that may very well give you bad query plans. Unless you have thousands of procedures you need to do find/replace in, you might want consider the extra effort of specifying the two different code paths. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: I would caution against using multiple execution paths. It can lead to very interesting performance problems. Gail Shaw has a great blog post on the topic here. http://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/09/15/multiple-execution-paths/

Comment: @SeanLange thanks for the link. I read through it and understood the possibility of different execution plans. So if I dont use different execution paths, that means I would always use `TOP(N)`. Then I need to check the N value to see if it is 0 or not. If it is 0, i could make `NumRows` = 2147483647 or `NumRows` = count(*) from table, what effect would this have on the query plan?

Comment: `SET ROWCOUNT` is not deprecated for `SELECT` statements, only for INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your procedure definition is something like this. It would be a LOT easier to help here if you posted the definition.

```
create procedure MyProc
(
    @NumRows int = 0
)
as 
    if @NumRows > 0
        set rowcount @NumRows
    else
        set rowcount 0

    select Columns
    from Table
```

Assuming the definition is like above you could change it to something like this.

```
create procedure MyProc
(
    @NumRows int = 2147483648 --max value for an int. This could be a bigint also if you have LOTS of data.
)
as 
    select top(@NumRows) Columns
    from Table
```

Please note that when using TOP you need to specify an order by or you have no way of knowing what rows will be returned.

--EDIT--

Thank you for the code example. It seems I was pretty close in my guess here. You don't have to use an IF statement here, you can accomplish this a little easier directly in your query. This is similar to the answer posted by lad2025.

```
select top(isnull(nullif(@NumRows, 0), 2147483647)) Columns
from Table
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of setting default to 2147483648. I also editted my original question to include how the stored procedure looks like. I think if current default is 0, we can change it to 2147483648. But if the default is currently not 0, then should we do, `if @NumRows = 0, set @NumRows = 2147483648`? Or simply use this IF statement in all default cases?

Comment: See my edit for an easier way than using an IF statement here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use subquery/expression in `TOP` clause instead of specific value:

```
DECLARE @param INT = 0;

SELECT TOP (SELECT IIF(@param=0,2000000, @param)) * FROM sys.objects;
SELECT TOP (IIF(@param=0,2000000, @param)) * FROM sys.objects;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/UIQZD35857)**

Be aware of possible performance implications. Also `TOP` without explicit `ORDER BY` may return different resultsets.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you elaborate on the possible performance implications? If you could share a few links, I can read those as well.